# PostgreSQL - how to select elements from a cursor in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, string-aggregation

I need to convert a query from Oracle SQL to Postgres. The query returns in a single row elements from a cursor. I'll write a simplified form of this query in Oracle:

```
select CONCAT_LIST( cursor( select first_name || '-' || last_name from sys_users)  ,',') as users_list from dual
```

If the table "sys_users" has 2 elements:

```
1. first name - "John", last name - "Smith"
2. first name - "George", last name - "Doe" ,
```

the result is:

```
John-Smith,George-Doe
```

I need to get the same result in Postgres, if the elements in this table are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To aggregate strings, use `string_agg()`

```
select string_agg(first_name || '-' || last_name, ',') as users_list
from sys_users;
```

Note that if `first_name` or `last_name` can be null, the result of the concatenation will also be null (unlike in Oracle). To get around that, use `concat()` instead which simply treats NULL as an empty string:

```
select string_agg(concat(first_name, '-', last_name), ',') as users_list
from sys_users;
```

Or even better: use `concat_ws()` which will leave out the `'-'` if an element is NULL:

```
select string_agg(concat_ws('-', first_name, last_name), ',') as users_list
from sys_users;
```

---

Btw: your Oracle query is overly complicated, you can essentially use the same as the first Postgres query if you replace `string_agg()` with `listagg()`

```
select listagg(firstname||'-'||lastname, ',') within group (order by lastname)
from sys_users;
```